# How to connect to a remote database in React Native?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, react-native

I'm creating an app for SQL-on-the-go, kind of like pgAdmin for mobile.

I want to connect to a remote database (let's say postgres, running on 1.2.3.4:5432).

The connection parameters will be configurable by the user.

All the questions/information on this topic are, rightfully so, advising to use an API instead. I think for this particular use case *it makes sense* to not do that (it's possible, sure, but would be a pain).

But I can't find any information on how to get my react native app to create a remote database connection directly.